# How to make form like example

Tags: wordpress, forms

there is this site https://www.delinski.at/ and it has a nice form where you can pick some values from dropdowns like Date, Number of Persons etc., and then submit the form. It redirects and I see the values on the redirected page link as parameters (if I have changed the defaults).

I searched for and tried several Form Plugins which all do not seem to work - most recent one (Form Maker) lets me design the form as I want but at the end I realized when I click on Submit, the values are not transfered to the target page (confirmed by Form Maker Support as work as intended). It's confusing because actually that should be a basic funciontality of a HTML form, right?

So I want to know if there are plugins where I can get a similar look&feel like the example given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site is a Static Site Generated framework not WordPress. That site would also be very expensive to build cause that is all coded, and very well:)
You are not actually seeing a form there at all that is just how PHP natively uses the URL to navigate via a button.

Almost all the form plug ins for WP use the database write now and do not pass the parameters of the entered form as a php _ POST with a redirect.

I kind of think what you really are looking for is a faceted search feature

One of the best that comes to my mind is [`https://facetwp.com/demo/cars/?_vehicle_type=truck`](https://facetwp.com/demo/cars/?_vehicle_type=truck)

Notice the car icons those are actually search buttons:) Of course you will have to build a template to do that neat stuff on the SSG site you linked but...

here is a [really informative write up](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/faceted-search/)on how it works to get started.